# Is it possible to access S3 objects from on-prem servers with automatically updating AWS credentials?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iis

I have a list of zip files stored in an S3 bucket that I would like to access from my web app which runs on an IIS server, outside AWS (on-prem). What would be the best way to handle the AWS credentials (I have a total of 4 environments - 4 IIS servers I need to maintain).

I know that I can manually set up an AWS credential profile (using an IAM user) using the AWS CLI on each environment but I was wondering if there would be a better way to handle the AWS credentials that are stored on the servers. For example, our organization has an IAM user policy that expires the credentials every **90** days. That means that there would be a bit of maintenance overhead requiring me to update the IAM user credentials all the machines every 90 days.

Is there a way to automate the above process so that the IAM user credentials are updated automatically?

Comment: Asking for *"better"* without explaining what *"better"* means to you is not going to produce valuable responses.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added a bit more context now

Comment: Doesn't read like a question for Stack Overflow. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create such a process yourself. There is nothing within AWS that can update credentials stored on your own computers.

IAM Users can have two active credentials, so the process would be:

- Generate second set of credentials on the IAM User
- Update credentials stored in your applications
- Disable/delete the first set of credentials from the IAM User

This gives some time for applications to update to the new credentials while the old credentials are still valid. These steps can be automated via API calls to AWS, but your own application would need to initiate the steps and update the credentials on your servers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I though that would be the case as it is outside AWS so there wouldn't be an easy way. Your answer does help, though. Your suggestion with the 2 sets of credentials is a good suggestion. I will start with that and investigate if I can implement something that will automate the process. 

Thanks! :)